# Brown leaves on avocado plant

Tags: avocado

Why are the edges of my avocado plant leaves turning brown?  It is kept indoors near a window with indirect light.  Should I cut it back to restart new leaves?  Could it be root bound?

Comment: Are there drafts by the window? Is there any kind of air outlet (like a heater vent) within 8' of it?

Comment: A picture might help. Brown edges (especially tips) could be leaf-burning from too much nitrogen, but it could be other things, too.

Comment: Welcome to the site!  Have you looked at the question kevinsky suggested as a possible duplicate of this? There's a lot of information on that question and answer, so you might find what you need. If not, would you let us know what's different about your problem? Definitely answering the questions in the comments here, and posting a picture or two would help too!